# How can I reduce memory usage of WPF application which use Prism Dialog Service?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am developing a WPF-Application using PRISM/Unity v7.2.0.1422 and the MVVM approach. I use Prism Dialog Service to show dialogs. Below are my codes.

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) {
 containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ProductListView>("ProductList");

 containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<CategoryEditorView, CategoryEditorViewModel>();

 containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MyRibbonWindow>();}
```

ProductListViewModel.cs

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("DockingRegion", typeof(ProductEditorView));
```

ProductEditorViewModel.cs

```
_dialogService.ShowDialog("CategoryEditorView", new DialogParameters { { "Title", Title } }, returned => {});
```

App starts with low memory usage but as continue using, memory build up and loading time take much longer especially when dialog open. When I view with ANTS memory profiler, everytime I open dialog, live instances of both Category and CategoryEditorViewModel go up. If I open 10 times, it go up by 10, etc... although other ViewModel like ProductEditorViewModel register in region remain same (1). I use dialog in other parts too and some contain a lot of controls and thus memory usage.

How can I counter this? Is is possible to reuse CategoryEditorView without creating new one everytime dialog open? Is my design wrong? What would be best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? The garbage collector eventually cleans up, right?

Comment: I am not sure garbage collector cleans up or not. I am sure that, as the app opened dialog, dialog opening time increase. Initially it take about 700ms and when open about 50-70 times, it increase up to 2000ms. And that is the problem.

Comment: When looking at your memory profiler, what keeps the controls in closed dialogs alive? Is it your code or the framework's?